# Потенциально проблемные места при программировании на PHP

Tags: php, code-style, css

К примеру, разработка ведется под виндой, а готовый проект разварачивается на линуксовом сервере. Вот пара потенциально проблемных моментов, с которыми я столкнулся:

1. При разработке под видой PHP лояльно относится к опущеным кавычкам в указании ключа массива: `$foo[bar]`. А вот линукс ругается и без кавычек работать отказывается: `$foo['bar']`. Поэтому лучше кавычки не опускать.
2. В PHP 5.3.0 появилась [волшебная константа](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php) `__DIR__` , но велика вероятность, что на хостинге до сих пор крутится более старая версия PHP, поэтому лучше использовать `dirname(__FILE__)` .

Поделитесь своими находками?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

О проблемах PHP [на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/142140/) довольно много и подробно расписано.

Comment: Отличный ответ ^_^    $a = 'aaa'; $b = 0;    var_dump($a == true && $b == false && $a == $b);

Comment: @AlexWindHope, подождите-ка. В случае приведения строки к булеву значению получается True (сравнили - все ок), а в случае приведения к числу - 0 (опять же, сравнили два нуля - все ок).

Comment: @Khvorostin если вы считаете такое поведение нормальным, то тогда, конечно, никаких проблем с PHP у вас не возникнет.

Кстати - с чего бы это не пустая строка приводилась к 0'ю?(это камень в PHP огород) Ну да неважно, главное что для вас такое поведение очевидно.

Просто, как по мне, абсолютно бредово выглядит:

    $str = 'some string';
    if($str && $str != 0) {
     // false
    }

Возможно кому-то такое даже нравиться, но не мне

Comment: @AlexWindHope, я не знаю, какое поведение нормально. Поэтому как раз было бы интересно услышать, где в моих рассуждениях ошибка. Я сделал так:

$i = 'Непустая строка';
echo (int)$i;

Вернулся ноль. Или я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: @Khvorostin - я бы сказал что-то не так делают создатели PHP...

Comment: @AlexWindHope, возможно. Но пока картина такая: приведение sting к int в PHP дает 0. Вопрос в том, что должно возвращаться в идеальном мире? Если вообще должно, конечно. Возможно, должна вываливаться ошибка.

Comment: @Khvorostin, одно я знаю точно, не пустая строка == 0 это полный бред. Если говорить о сравнении строк с числами, то мне нравиться как это реализовано в "JS подобных" языках, но все это возможно благодаря NaN:

    // дабы было понятно
    NaN > 0  // false
    NaN < 0  // false
    NaN == 0 // false
    Number('str') // NaN
    Number('\t\n\n        \t\t') // 0

    '\t\n   ' == 0 // true
    '\t\n a ' == 0 // false
    'str' == 0     // false
    'str' > 0      // false
    'str' < 0      // false

Comment: В общем-то такого рода проблемы решаются повсеместным использованием `===` вместо `==`, но, к сожалению, практикуется это не часто и уж точно не везде и не всегда

Comment: О! Про NaN-то я и забыл. Хороший вариант, да.